# I want to call a function which is written in "C" DLL from node.js javascript?

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, electron

I want to call a function which is written in "C" DLL from node.js javascript. I am using "ffi" module in node.js and electron. The function which I want to call is "int FDColor_GetSWVersion(char* softwareVersion)". I am using the below code:

```
 var libm = ffi.Library(__dirname + "\\viewmodels\\FDColor.dll", {
      'FDColor_GetSWVersion': [ 'int', ['string' ] ]
    });
```

But I am getting the error "Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 126". Could anyone please help me out

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/14362289/2703418 ?

Comment: Error 126 is "the specified module could not be found". Sure you're passing the right path?

Comment: Path is correct. I think the issue should be the parameter type which is passing in the function (char* softwareVersion), which is not compatible with string. I don't know the cause :(

Comment: @bzeaman I have installed the .exe and checked the result but there is no such error traced :(

Comment: Run `dumpbin /exports FDColor.dll` -- is FDColor_GetSWVersion listed?

Comment: @LouFranco where should I run this command?

Comment: From a command prompt in the folder where FDColor.dll is -- I actually don't think this is the issue any more (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get "the specified module cannot be found", this refers to the DLL you tried to load or any of its dependencies.

You have given a full path to the `ffi.Library` function, but when FDColor.dll loads its dependencies it will probably use no path, which causes LoadLibrary to look first in the current-working-directory of the process and then in the directories of the PATH environment variable.

So,

1. Use DependencyWalker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on FDColor.dll to see if it has any dependencies.  The best way to do that is to call it from the same place as you call this script (giving the same path you pass to ffi.Library).
2. For each DLL it would try to load, but is not found, you need to add the folder to the PATH environment variable of the environment that calls this script.
3. You can check that you have done this right by repeating step 1 after setting PATH at the command prompt. DependencyWalker will now show that it can find those DLLs.

Comment: It's displaying error 
"Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module."

Comment: Great -- move on to step 2 :) -- it might help to show some screenshots of what is happening in your question.

Comment: It was working when I was creating sample. Now I have implemented this into my real project and its throwing the error "Uncaught Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 193". Could you please help me out here?

Comment: You should make a new question

Comment: I have created.. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843150/error-with-ffi-module-node-js-uncaught-error-dynamic-linking-error-win32-error