# Error with ffi module node.js Uncaught Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 193

Tags: javascript, c, node.js, electron

I want to call a function, which is written in "C" DLL, from node.js JavaScript. I am using "ffi" module in node.js and electron. The function which I want to call is "int FDColor_GetSWVersion(char* softwareVersion)". I am using the below code:

```
  var libm = ffi.Library(__dirname + "\\viewmodels\\FDColor.dll", {
  'FDColor_GetSWVersion': [ 'int', ['string' ] ]
   });
```

But I am getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Dynamic Linking Error: Win32 error 193

Comment: Anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that error means you have a 32/64 bit mismatch. You need to build the dll to match the loading process.

Answer (score 0):

I chose the 64-bit DLL and loaded it successfully