# I always get a 126 LoadLibrary error when trying to load dll

Tags: c++, loadlibrary

When I'm trying to load nss3.dll  to load some functions, i get a 126 error.
Dll located in C:\TEMP
Code:

```
    SetDllDirectory("C:\\TEMP");
    HMODULE hNSS = LoadLibrary("nss3.dll");
    if (hNSS)
    {
    cout << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
    cout << GetLastError();
    }
```

I tried write it differently, but i always get this error.

Comment: maybe take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361992/dll-load-library-error-code-126

Comment: `nss3.dll` is likely dependent on several other dlls. Are they in the PATH? You may want to use [Dependency Walker 2.2](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)